# Junit Code Coverage for Custom Row Mapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have written a Test class for getEmployeeDetails Method contains a procedure which will return employee details in a cursor, a custom row mapper implemented to map those fields.

I am able to mock the StoredProcedure call in the method and execute the method, But when i look at the code coverage Custom Row Mapper is not included as part of the Code Coverage

**Below is My Repository Class**

```
public class EmployeeRepository {

@Autowired
private JdbcRepository jdbcRepository

public List<Employee> getEmployeeDetails() {


        SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new SqlParameter[] {
                new SqlOutParameter("employeedetails", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new EmployeeListHandler()) };

        Map<String, Object> result = jdbcRepository.executeProcedure("employee_list_proc", sqlParameters, new HashMap<>());

        return (List<Employee>) result.get("employeedetails");



}
private class EmployeeListHandler implements RowMapper<Employee> {
    @Override
    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        Employee employee = new Employee();

        employee.setId(rs.getLong("id");
        employee.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        
        // Rest of the employee Attributes 


        return employee;
    }
}
}
```

**Below Is My Custom JbdcRepository Class**

```
public Class JdbcRepository {

   public Map<String, Object> executeProcedure(String procedureName, SqlParameter[] sqlParameters,
        Map<String, Object> inputParams){

    StoredProcedure procedure = new GenericStoredProcedure();
    setDataSource(procedure);
    procedure.setSql(procedureName);
    procedure.setFunction(false);
    procedure.setParameters(sqlParameters);
    return procedure.execute(inputParams);

   }
}
```

**Below Is my Test Class**

```
@Mock
private JdbcRepository jdbcRepository;

@Mock
private ResultSet rs;
    
@InjectMocks
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;


@Test
public void testEmployeeDetails() throws Exception{
    
   when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
   
   when(rs.getString(anyString())).thenReturn("TEST");
   
   when(jdbcRepository.executeProcedure(anyString(), any(SqlParameter[].class),
            anyMap())).thenReturn(new HashMap<>());
    
    employeeRepository.getEmployeeDetails();
    
    verify(jdbcRepository, times(1)).executeProcedure(anyString(), any(SqlParameter[].class),
            anyMap());
    
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(jdbcRepository);
}
```

I have mocked the resultset, But still Code coverage is not included for the EmployeeListHandler, Not sure where i am doing wrong ..

Edit 1: If i am doing wrong, what is alternative way to get the complete code coverage .

Answer (score 1):

Notice that here:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeeDetails() {


        SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new SqlParameter[] {
                new SqlOutParameter("employeedetails", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new EmployeeListHandler()) };

        Map<String, Object> result = jdbcRepository.executeProcedure("employee_list_proc", sqlParameters, new HashMap<>());

        return (List<Employee>) result.get("employeedetails");



}
```

You created `sqlParameters` and added `EmployeeListHandler` object as one if it's parameters.

Then You used `sqlParameters` with `executeProcedure` so your overridden function `mapRow` is supposed to be called when `executeProcedure` is called, but you also
mocked it's call

```
  when(jdbcRepository.executeProcedure(anyString(), any(SqlParameter[].class),
            anyMap())).thenReturn(new HashMap<>());
```

so there's no coverage on this function as it's never being called when you test it.

Answer for edit:
You should test MapRow separately.

And also, I'm not sure what you're trying to test here since almost all your function calls are mocked so this test doesn't really test anything.

If you want to actually test a real call to the repository you'll need to setup one and test it.

Comment: Thanks Raz, What is the alternative way to get the complete Code Coverage... Updated the question .

Comment: @karthikmunna did you get any solution to this? If yes please post your answer